# Update Apache, PHP on Red Hat 7

Tags: apache-2.2, php, redhat

I have an ancient server running Red Hat 7.  I would like to update the httpd set up and obviously Red Hat does not provide updates for a system this old.  What would be the best method to update these services on this machine?

Answer (score 3):

Honestly your best bet may be to update the OS. You're going to have to compile from source and chances are you will be compiling dependencies of the Apache and PHP from the source too.

You may have some luck getting the rpms from a source like this [rpm.pbone.net](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/2404783/dir/redhat_7.x/com/php-4.1.2-7.i386.rpm.html)

Comment: +1 for rpm.pbone. Excellent resource for nonstandard rpms.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy. I owe that site countless plugs for the time they have saved me.

Comment: re: rpm.pbone how can the origin of these packages be verified? ie. how do we know they haven't been tampered with?

Comment: It's been a trusted source in oss for many years. You can download the source rpms and look at them. You can sort by trusted vendors like the fedora project. You can contact the maintainer of the site and read the FAQ for more information. If you're really worried I would suggest you just compile everything from source. I think that's the road you will be heading down anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Compile last(or needed) versions of Apache and PHP from sources

Comment: and whose to say that php 5 and apache 2 will compile with this vintage of 2.4 kernel?

Comment: @Joe P. Good point. It's likely to be a messy venture.